# Openlayers API Docs

Tags: openlayers

I've heard that the older versions of API docs got removed because of disk space issues in git pages but I can't find the docs anywhere else, it seems like they completely deleted every other API docs but the latest one, which is a lot different and need too much time to be interpreted for older versions.

Anyone got a copy of "^4.6.2" versions, before or after?

Or would you suggest to use another opensource map library?

Comment: Documentation is longer on the OL site but all old versions including documentation can still be downloaded https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v4.6.2
4.6.5 is still on the OL site http://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/index.html and with a few exceptions is correct for 4.6.2
Full builds are available on cdn services https://cdnjs.com/libraries/openlayers/4.6.2

Comment: Thanks ! Tried to find the doc via url too but could'nt figure out the right url. Thx

Answer (score 1):

See "Older versions" on the bottom of https://openlayers.org/. We're keeping the latest version of the docs of previous major releases, and all revisions of the current major release.

You can download an offline version of all docs from the release page. The full zip under "Assets" contains the API docs in the `apidoc/` folder, e.g. `v4.6.2.zip` from the https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v4.6.2 page.